# what's the difference between these two different initialization for a string in c++？

Tags: c++, string, initialization

The source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::string s{'a', 'b', '\0', 'c'};
    std::string s1="ab\0c";
    cout<<s.size()<<" "<<s<<endl;
    cout<<s1.size()<<" "<<s1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
4 abc
2 ab
```

I wonder why this phenomenon occurs and are there any difference between these two types of initialization in C++? Thanks.

Comment: I can't copy paste pictures

Comment: You should put your source code directly in your question in the form of text. Many users won't even look at code in the form of a screen shot.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code and output. Remove the pictures please.

Comment: This is my first time to ask a question and I'm sorry. I have fixed it and thanks again.

Comment: It's unfortunate how quick users are to down vote first posts rather than correcting the new users on their mistakes.

Comment: a general tip, don't use `endl` unless you specifically *need* to have the buffers flushed. Just use `"\n"` instead. When writing to a terminal console it will usually be line buffered anyway and when writing to some other pipe you do not incur the unnecessary overhead of flushing your buffers every time.

Comment: Got it! Thanks wich! I don't know why endl can incur the unnecessary overhead. Could you explain it to me? I just start my C++ journey.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `s` you're matching the constructor that accepts an initialiser-list of characters: that's (9) in the list [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).  The `string` class lets you construct strings from arbitrary data which may include embedded NULs, as it does in this case.  The initialiser list knows its own length, so the `string` captures all the characters.

For `s1`, the matching constructor is (5) in the above-linked list, which accepts a `const char*` - the compiler lets the array of char provided decay to such a pointer before calling that constructor, which means the constructor has no knowledge of the length of the array.  Instead, it assumes you're deliberately using the ASCIIZ NUL-terminated string convention (as in "C" strings), and scans through the data to find the first NUL, considering that the terminator.  Consequently, only 2 characters are captured in the string.

Note that you can explicitly capture 4 characters with...

```
std::string s1 { "ab\0c", 4};
```

...which matches constructor (4) in the list.

Rakete1111's comment below illustrates another, newer way to create such strings: `auto s1 = "ab\0c"s;`.

Comment: Thanks, you help me understand more. Usually, I don't notice these differences. I should pay more attention to the constructor of STL. And by the way, is that means the second way is similar to char s[ ]="ab\0c" in C?

Comment: You're welcome.  Regarding `char s[ ]="ab\0c"` in C - yes and no - `s` there would capture all 4 characters, but if you passed it to a function expecting a `const char*`would decay, so e.g. `strdup(s)` would return a new buffer lacking the final `'c'`, similar to the `string` constructor behaviour.  Hope that helps clarify things!

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for cleared up the confusion and I learned a lot!

Comment: You could also use string literals: `auto s1 = "ab\0c"s;`

Comment: @Rakete1111: good point - I wish all the compilers I've had to work with recently supported that already!

Comment: Thanks Rakete1111. I knew auto but what's the ‘s’ behind the string meaning?

Comment: @LixunBai: it's documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), but the simple version is that the `s` "behind the string" (as you put it) means to construct a `std::string` large enough for the entire string literal including any embedded NUL characters.

Comment: @Tony D: Thanks. I appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that std::strings are not first class objects, they are standard library objects and have to obey the rules of C++ syntax. Unlike string literals which are first class constructs.

An std::string is allowed embedded nuls, so when it is initialised to an array, it sees the whole of the array. When it is initialised to a string literal, it sees a char *, and its only way of detecting string end is to search for the null.

Comment: The reason has nothing to do with whether `std::string`s are "first class objects" or obey rules of "C syntax" (which they certainly do not).

Comment: Interestingly, C++ actually provides end-user and library code enough power to capture the length of a string literal constructor argument - e.g. `template <size_t N> string(char (&arg)[N]) { ...can use N in body... };`,  It's the `std::string` API that chooses not to use that approach.

Comment: FYI: `{'a', 'b', '\0', 'c'}` is not an array.  It is a `std::initialization_list<char>`.  Technically a string literal is an array.  It has the type of `const char[N]`.